# select command error on refreshing page continuously

Tags: c#, performance

I am developing a banking application in which I have written a helper class.
What happens is whenever I continuously, 5 to 7 or more times, press the refresh button, it gives me this error: `Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.`

Can any body specify what I am missing in my code, or what more could I do to make it better to perform without any error?

My helper class function is :

```
    private static OdbcCommand cmd;
    private static OdbcDataAdapter da;
    private static DataTable dt;


    public static void GetDataInDataGrid(string sp_Name, GridView gv)
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            using (cmd = new OdbcCommand(sp_Name))
            {
                cmd.Connection = Connection.ConnString.ConnectionString;
                using (da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd))
                {

                    da.Fill(dt);
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        gv.DataSource = dt;
                        gv.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

The error is occurring in the below code, at the throw statement

```
try
  {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
      herlperUtility.GetDataInDataGrid("{ CALL asp_sp_GetDataForSupervisor }", this.gvSuperviseDataGrid);
      if (this.gvSuperviseDataGrid.DataSource == null)
      {
        this.divFailure.InnerText = "No Records Found!!!";
        this.divFailure.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block;margin-top:20px;");
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw ex;
  }
```

Comment: This sure is a lot of code. Now where does the error occur?

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
using (cmd = new OdbcCommand(sp_Name,Connection.ConnString.ConnectionString))
```

inplace of

```
 using (cmd = new OdbcCommand(sp_Name))
            {
                cmd.Connection = Connection.ConnString.ConnectionString;
```